# Spotify API error: "response_type must be code or token"

Tags: swift, spotify

Hello i am trying to build a spotify app on swift.
Following a youtube guide so far...
Getting the following error when trying to login:
response_type must be code or token

my URL:
`\(base)?repsonse_type=code&client_id=\(Constants.clientID)&scope=\(scopes)&redirect_uri=\(redirectURI)&show_dialog=TRUE`

where Base:
`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize`

I can see someone has asked about the same a year ago but with no response..

Comment: Could it be that "repsonse" is not "response" in the URL ?

Comment: Is `redirectURI` correctly percent escaped as it could include parameters that break the parsing of the parameters?

Comment: Thanks @Larme, That was the case for me.